# RecyclerView not scrolling with SwipeLayout

Tags: android-recyclerview, layout, scroll

I have SwipeLayout and include ConstraintLayout layout with RecyclerView on it.
but RecyclerView not scrolling.

```
<ru.rambler.libs.swipe_layout.SwipeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <include layout="@layout/constraintLayout_with_recyclerView" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <include layout="@layout/undo_layout" />
```

ConstraintLayout with RecyclerView

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />
```